# Is there a term for "inner perimeter/circumference"?

Tags: phrase-requests

A square box will have an outer perimeter and a smaller inner perimeter. A cylindrical box will have an outer and inner circumference.

Are there common words or technical terms for an inner perimeter and/or circumference?

This presumes that a "perimeter" or "circumference" is typically assumed to be outer, which is my impression.

Comment: *Is there a common word or technical term for an "inner circumference"?* No.

Comment: 'Outer circumference' and 'inner circumference' are technical terms, often used for say cylindrical tanks and discs (eg washers).

Comment: Your question isn't clear, because "circumference" is usually a property of circles, which are two-dimensional (unlikes boxes) and have no straight edges (also unlike boxes). Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Are you referring to the two circles that can be drawn within the walls of a box and around the corners of a box?

Comment: Apologies – I did not realise "circumference" would not be appropriate for a square box, but that makes sense, of course. Now hopefully clarified.

Comment: Bear in mind that the word perimeter is usually used in things like land and building surveying and describing and not to describe boxes. Whereas circumference is a term from geometry. As for inner/outer that can go with either one.

Comment: Yeah, neither "perimeter" nor "circumference" go well with the box example, do they… I honestly can no longer remember the real underlying question I had and if it had anything to do with boxes, but I'm learning from the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a term for "inner circumference"?

Only on circular objects.

Otherwise, it is an "internal **perimeter**" which, as we will see, is a useless measurement.

Assume a box of exterior dimensions 20cm height, 41cm width and 32cm depth that has, for example, internal dimensions of 19cm height, 40cm width and 30cm depth.

This has

three external perimeters = 2(width + height) = 122cm; 2(height + depth) = 104cm , and 2(width + depth) = 146cm and

and

three internal perimeters = 2(width + height) = 118cm; 2(height + depth) = 100cm, and 2(width + depth) = 142cm.

You will now note that of the 6 perimeters, no two are the same.

You will also note that, for a general box, it is uncertain which side is the top, bottom, or side

For these reason, there is no easy solution to your description.

The effect of this is that as a general concept what you are asking must be described as a clause.

Even in a specific case, where the orientation of the box is known, it ***may*** be possible to describe the internal and external (width + depth) measurement as “the **horizontal perimeter**” but this leaves the two dimensions that include height as undescribed and indescribable in a short phrase.

Out of interest, do you have specific terms in your language?

Comment: I didn't notice any indication that the OP is familiar with a language other than English...

Comment: I think you are assuming that the box in question is a cardboard carton or something similar. The inner circumferemce of a small box made from thick wood (for instance) would be considerably smaller, proportionally, than its outside circumference.

Comment: @BoldBen With the words "assume" and "for example", it should be obvious that the actual measurements can be anything at all - as long as each exterior dimension is greater than its equivalent interior.

Comment: Fair enough with circumference only applying to a cylindrical box. Now clarified in the question. Regarding the ambiguity of exactly which sides one is referring to, I don't see that as a problem – it could be the case that there are terms for some of those, or some broader term that would apply to all of them.

Comment: I don't believe I asked because I had some term in another language in mind – but I do speak Swedish where I suppose "innermått" (literally "inner measurements"/"inner dimensions") is used for this purpose.

Comment: On the broad question, we do use "internal dimensions/measurements."

Comment: Circles don't have perimeters; those are for buildings, land, surveying etc. Not geometry/

Comment: @Lambie That is not so. OED **perimeter**, n. 1.a. **A continuous line forming the boundary of a closed geometrical figure or of any area or surface; a circumference; a periphery, outline.** Also: the length of this. -- 1991   Offshore Engineer Sept. 102/1   *The risers are held around the perimeter of a 27m diameter circle in the ends of radial spider arms formed in flexible composite material.*

Comment: You just proved my point. The OED thingie is referring to a real thing. Around the perimeter of a 27m diameter circle is physical location in that engineering document, not geometric. A box does not have a perimeter. You can draw a line on the ground to make one for it though.

Comment: @Lambie I think you have genuinely misunderstood. The boundary and the perimeter are the same thing. Boundary is used to define a limit and is often used figuratively; a perimeter is a length. However, and otherwise, there is no distinction.

Comment: The circumference of a circle is C=2πr in geometry. Not called a perimeter.

Comment: The circumference of a circle is the length of the perimeter of that circle. The concepts differ - see above. This is why we have a **perimeter** fence but not a **circumference** fence".

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what the questioner means, but should be said: Geometric shapes are defined by line segments that have no "thickness" or any dimension other than length. The question assumes that the "inside" perimeter and the "outside" perimeter of a box (rectangle) or the inside and outside circumference of a circle are not the same. In fact, mathematically, they are the same.

Of course, for physical objects with actual walls, the inside and outside measurements are different. But these are not the same as "perimeter" and "circumference", which are mathematical terms with precise definitions.

If you are looking for what to call these actual measurements, "inside" and "outside" measurements or dimensions are clear enough.

Comment: Good distinction. I meant for real-world shapes.